# CSS overwrites only some values

Tags: padding, font-size, overwrite, css

I have this CSS declaration:

```
.columns {
    width: 950px;
    font-family: verdana, arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
.newsfeed .description {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px!important;
}
```

`newsfeed description` is a div inside the `columns` div.

The problem is I can't seem to overwrite the line-height value of 21px to 14px.. I noticed this problem recently and it seems that it applies to paddings as well.

So, font-size, color etc. are overwritten, but not paddings and line-height (at least that's what I know of).

Where do you think might be the problem?

Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

Ok, I found my problem.

1. `description` was a span inside a div, so the problem is not the selector.
2. The values were inherited correctly according to chrome's developer tools.
3. The actual problem was that I did not know it wasn't possible to change the line-height of a inline element (such as the span I was using). I've changed the display of the span to block and it worked wonderfuly.

Thanks to everybody!

Comment: Use `.newsfeed.description` (without space) if you want to select an element like `<div class="newsfeed description">`

Comment: If you're using Chrome or Firefox, use their Developer Tools or Firebug respectively to check to see which class is taking precedence over the newer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe `newsfeed description` as being "a div" (singular). If you really mean that, and it is defined `<div class="newsfeed description">` then you're using the wrong selector, as `.newsfeed .description` would select only "description" class elements *inside* "newsfeed" class elements.

If that was the issue, you wouldn't be able to target that element with any of the rules in that selector. (Easy way to test... Add `display: none;` to the rules and see if the element disappears.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the space you have between ".newsfeed" and ".description". Remove the space and it will fix the error:

```
.newsfeed.description {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px!important;
}
```

The space indicates to CSS to look for an element with the class "description" which is contained within another element with the class "newsfeed". In order to tell CSS to look for an element which contains both class "newsfeed" and "description", you need to remove the space.

You should take the time to look over a tutorial on [CSS](http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need a better selector. Try the following:

.columns .newsfeed .description

or

.columns .newsfeed.description (if newsfeed and description are classes on the same div)

or

try putting an ID on the div you're targeting and style it specifically:

```
<div id="target">
```

with: #target {line-height:14px}